# Jquery UI datepicker change button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

Hello I have a button here and when click it shows the calendar:

[image]

[image]

What I want to achieve is that when a date is picked, the button text and image will be replace by e.g. 22-07-2016, so far no luck with changing it.

```
<input name="depart" id="depart">

$( "#depart" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: null,
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
showOn: "button",
buttonText: "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>Depart<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down'></span>",
});
```

I have tried a variety of methods such:

```
onSelect: function(date) {
        buttonText: date,
},
```

Comment: instead of modify the buttonText var, did you try select your button in jquery and replace the text ?

Comment: It is not a button, it is an <input>, so I couldn't add a text to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to set the value of the option using `option`.
Try,

```
onSelect: function(date) {
    $(this).datepicker('option', 'buttonText', date);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

as per the syntax in the documentation for setting options after the initial load, you should do it like this:

```
onSelect: function(date)
{
    $(this).datepicker("option", "buttonText", date);
}
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonText